# Makefile: automatically compile source for every included header

Tags: c++, c, makefile, automation

Can I configure my makefile in a way that it automatically compiles and links `foo/bar.cpp` if a target includes `#include "foo/bar.hpp"`?

Details: I have a makefile for a project structured like this:

```
src/
|-- program1/
|   |-- main.cpp
|   |-- makefile
|-- modules/
|   |-- module1/
|   |   |-- foo.cpp
|   |   |-- foo.hpp
|   |-- module1/
|   |   |-- bar.cpp
|   |   |-- bar.hpp
```

Currently my makefile for program1 contains a list of all the *.cpp files of all the modules it uses, which is kind of hard and error-prone to maintain and to keep in sync with my includes.

However, in my code, following the `#include` commands would provide an exact dependency-tree. For every *.hpp there is a corresponding *.cpp that I need to compile and link.

Can this process of compilation be automated via the makefile? May auto-dependencies help me out?

The makefile in question:

```
# compiler settings
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14
# object file generation path
tmpDir = .objs
# modules path
modPath = ../modules

# Names of modules and files to be compiled
names := \
    main.o \
    module1/foo.o \
    module2/bar.o

# prepend tmpDir
names := $(addprefix $(tmpDir)/, $(names))

# Linking
main: $(names)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o main $^

# Rule for main file
$(tmpDir)/main.o: main.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(tmpDir)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp -o $@ -I "$(modPath)"

# rules for module files
$(tmpDir)/%.o: $(modPath)/%.cpp
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o main $(tmpDir)
```

I'd like to avoid to manually set `names`.

Comment: What are the modules exactly here? Just source code directories, or does each module compile to a specific library?

Comment: Ah, they're plain source code directories. No separate compilation intended. Also, they may include each other.

Comment: Would you consider using a build generation tool like CMake? It has powerful abstractions (functions, macros...) that would help you avoid having to repeat yourself for such a usecase.

Comment: `GCC` can be made to output all the header dependencies in a format that can be read by a `Makefile`. See: flags `-MMD -MP`. If you post a sample `Makefile` I could try to post an answer showing how it would work. (assuming you use `GCC`)

Comment: Personally I would be more concerned about automatically re-compiling all changed compilation units whenever a source or header file changes. Completely forgetting to list a .cpp file in the Makefile will soon be brought to your attention via unresolved symbol errors

Comment: I will check out CMake. Anyways it would be great to find a Makefile solution. I have been looking into -MMD auto-dependencies for a while, but couldn't make it do what I wanted it to do.
This is my makefile:
https://pastebin.com/huiFt2rG

Comment: @Simon Can you post your Makefile in the question?

Comment: There are a few problems with the referenced makefile.  The most obvious is the text of the makefile is not part of the question.

Comment: Ok, I added the makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to automate generating the file names is using a `$(wildcard ...)` or some `$(shell ...)` command to scan the directories.

Based on the `Makefile` you linked I think you can track the dependencies using `GCC` with the `-MMD -MP` flags something like this:

```
# compiler settings
CXX = g++
# use flags to generate dependency files
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14 -MMD -MP
# object file generation path
tmpDir = .objs
# modules path
modPath = ../modules

# Names of modules and files to be compiled
names := main.o
names += $(patsubst $(modPath)/%.cpp,%.o,$(shell find $(modPath) -iname "*.cpp"))

# prepend tmpDir
names := $(addprefix $(tmpDir)/, $(names))

# there should be a dep file for every object file
deps  := $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$(names))

all: main

# Linking
main: $(names)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o main $^

# Rule for main file
$(tmpDir)/main.o: main.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(tmpDir)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp -o $@ -I "$(modPath)"

# rules for module files
$(tmpDir)/%.o: $(modPath)/%.cpp
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# include the dependencies if they exist    
-include $(deps)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o main $(tmpDir) $(deps)
```

Every compile command that uses the `-MMD -MP` flags will generate a dependency file corresponding to the output file (except with a `.d` extension).

Comment: Ok, now, that list of `names` is what I want to circumvent. Can I add a rule, that compiles the corresponding *.cpp file for every *.hpp file in the dependencies?

Comment: regarding: `$(tmpDir)/%.o: $(modPath)/%.cpp`  1) This is missing the `%.d` dependency.  2) This will not recurse down into the directory where the source file is located.

Comment: @Simon I have added a means to generate your `names` using a `$(shell ...)` command.

Comment: regarding: `mkdir -p $(dir $@)`   this will try to create the same directory for each source file.  This will be a problem because after the first source file, the directory will already exist.

Comment: @user3629249 I am just presenting the Makefile OP linked in the comments above. It is probably better to suggest improvements there.

Comment: Note:  "# include the contents of all the .d files
# note: the .d files contain:
# <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependancies for that .c file 
# I.E. the #include'd header files
# wrap with ifneg... so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean'
#
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif"

Comment: @user3629249 Not sure if I understand you correctly but you don't need to rebuild the `.d` files after a clean. The dependencies don't matter  when you have to rebuild the whole project. Only when you modified a small part of it that was already built.

Comment: all the compile steps can be done with a recipe similar to: `"$(tmpDir)/%.o: %.cpp %.d <tab>@mkdir -p $(tmpDir) <tab>$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I $>

Comment: my comment about the wrapper for the `#include` command is to AVOID having the `make` facility rebuilding the `*.d` files when the target is `clean`

Comment: I have a 'vague' memory that when the compiler optiions: `-MMD -MP` are used that the actual compile is not performed, so need a separate recipe for the actual compiles

Comment: @user3629249 The compile is performed. Dependency generation is a byproduct of that. I have tested this makefile and the dependencies appear to be working fine.

Comment: First of all, thank all of you for your suggestions! It still doesn't fullfil everything I hoped. It compiles also the modules not included, but I guess that's the price. More importantly, there are some *.cpp's containing tests in the module directories, which must not be included in the compilation, as they contain main() methods. Maybe it is possible to refine the `find` to match only when both a foo.cpp and foo.hpp are present?

Comment: @Simon It's not magic. You either have to give it specific file names or else find some rule to select exactly the files you want.

Answer (score 0):

regarding: *Currently my makefile for program1 contains a list of all the *.cpp files of all the modules it uses, which is kind of hard and error-prone to maintain and to keep in sync with my includes.

However, in my code, following the #include commands would provide an exact dependency-tree. For every *.hpp there is a corresponding *.cpp that I need to compile and link.

Can this process of compilation be automated via the makefile? May auto-dependencies help me out?*

In the makefile, you could use the output of a call to the `find` command to obtain a list of all the (for instance) *.cpp files in the directories below the `modules` directory rather than hard-coding the list.

Answer (score 0):

I refined Galik's answer a bit. Now it behaves much like what I was searching for.

Instead of defining `names` manually, I invoke a search for files. The results then filters to match only *.cpp files that have a *.hpp file with the same name. This ignores all files containing the tests:

```
# find *.hpp files
names := $(shell find $(modPath) -iname "*.hpp")
# replace extension .hpp -> .cpp
names := $(patsubst %,%.cpp,$(basename $(names)))
# filter nonexistent *.cpp files
names := $(wildcard $(names))
```